# How to overload same named methods of different interfaces with type annotations in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, interface, polymorphism, overloading

So I have Python 3 code like this:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
from datetime import datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
class IfaceA(ABC):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    @abstractmethod                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    def pass_data(self, data: str):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        pass                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
class IfaceB(ABC):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    @abstractmethod                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    def pass_data(self, data: datetime):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        pass                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
class MyClass(IfaceA, IfaceB):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    def pass_data(self, data: str):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        print("str", data)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    def pass_data(self, data: datetime):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        print("datetime", data)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
def main():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    c = MyClass()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    c.pass_data("Any string.")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    c.pass_data(datetime.now())                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    main()
```

and it gives me output like this:

```
datetime Any string.
datetime 2020-07-13 02:00:34.676715
```

The **IfaceA.pass_data** method with str argument was not used.

Is there a way to make this work like in C++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use multimethod

```
 from abc import ABC, abstractmethod                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
from datetime import datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
from multimethod import multimethod
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
class IfaceA(ABC):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    @abstractmethod                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    def pass_data(self, data: str):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        pass                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
class IfaceB(ABC):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    @abstractmethod                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    def pass_data(self, data: datetime):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        pass                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
class MyClass(IfaceA, IfaceB):
    @multimethod                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    def pass_data(self, data: str):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        print("str", data)
    @multimethod                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    def pass_data(self, data: datetime):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        print("datetime", data)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
def main():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    c = MyClass()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    c.pass_data("Any string.")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    c.pass_data(datetime.now())                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    main()
```

Comment: TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases.

I think because ABC is not a pure interface and we have a Diamond-Problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's doable without some ugly non-pythonic hacks. The best you can do without hacks or 3rd party libs (with hacks) is this.

```
from datetime import datetime
from functools import singledispatchmethod


class MyClass:
    @singledispatchmethod
    def pass_data(self, val):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @pass_data.register
    def prints_str(self, data: str):
        print("str", data)


    @pass_data.register
    def prints_datetime(self, data: datetime):
        print("datetime", data)


def main():
    c = MyClass()
    c.pass_data("Any string.")
    c.pass_data(datetime.now())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```